# Bootstrap 3 long columns push others down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

The first picture above is exactly what I want, but the other pictures show what I am getting

Using Bootstrap 3:

Trial 1: As seen in the second picture, the side bar `col-sm-2` pushes the `col-sm-8` down when its height is not the same as the height of its corresponding column:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-8">1</div>
       <div class="col-sm-2">2</div>
       <div class="col-sm-8">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Trial 2: As seen in the third picture, the side bar aligns with the second `col-sm-8` but I want it to be aligned horizontally with the first column:

```
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">2</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

If I do something like the following, it works fine, but I want the `col-sm-2` to be on the right hand side:

```
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">2</div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">1</div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">3</div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.  Your just missing a couple of divs.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">3</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">2</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```